# Date & Time Separation

Tags: c#, asp.net, timezone

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <input id="inpHide" type="hidden" runat="server" />
        <input id="inpHide1" type="hidden" runat="server" />
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Width="100px" Height="30px" Text="Button" />
    </div>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        var current_date = new Date();
        var current_timezone = current_date.getTimezoneOffset();
        document.getElementById("inpHide").value = current_timezone * -1;
        document.getElementById("inpHide1").value = current_date;
        </script>
</body>
</html>

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Label1.Text = inpHide.Value.Trim();
            Label2.Text = inpHide1.Value.Trim();
            Label3.Text = Label2.Text;
}
```

Comment: It's not really clear what your input and output types are here. Please could you clarify?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
DateTime dt;
string Temp1 = "Your Date";
if (Temp1.LastIndexOf("GMT") > 0)
{
    Temp1 = Temp1.Remove(Temp1.LastIndexOf("GMT"));
}
Temp1 = "Wed May 25 23:43:31 UTC+0900 2011";
if (Temp1.LastIndexOf("UTC") > 0)
{
     Temp1 = Temp1.Remove(Temp1.LastIndexOf("UTC"), 9);
     string[] split = Temp1.Split(' ');
     Temp1 = split[0] + " " + split[1] + " " + split[2] + " " + split[4] + " " + split[3];
}
if (DateTime.TryParse(Temp1, out dt))
{
     // If it is a valid date
     string date = dt.ToShortDateString();
     string time = dt.ToShortTimeString();
}
```

Comment: string Temp1="Wed May 25 2011 19:15:49 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)";
From the above string Temp1, i need to separate "may 25 2011" alone from Temp1. so that i may string Temp2="25/05/2011";

Comment: The format you mentioned should be prepared on trimming the after GMT part and finally after validation.

Comment: Sorry SQL, your code is not properly working. during debugging the function is not coming inside the "if" loop.

Comment: sorry for giving wrong answer, your code is working. if suppose string Temp1="Wed May 25 23:43:31 UTC+0900 2011".. your code is not working at that time.

Comment: i agree with your answer SQL, but one problem still exist in GMT the year comes in front of it, but in UTC the year comes after it. if i use your code my code works for GMT but not with UTC with respect to year detection.

Comment: string Temp1="Wed May 25 23:43:31 UTC+0900 2011";

Comment: I am looking into it please wait

Comment: Sorry SQL, i not getting like that.. i will attach my code please go through it.

Comment: Can you provide a sample link using year value comes after UTC?

Comment: I want to know, that do you have any sample link on net which describes the UTC format as mentioned by you ?

Comment: I used this script to get the date.. go through it and send feedback if u have on this script................................................... <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        var current_date = new Date();
        var current_timezone = current_date.getTimezoneOffset();
        document.getElementById("inpHide").value = current_timezone * -1;
        document.getElementById("inpHide1").value = current_date;
        </script>

Comment: Sure. Let me know if you need any help. Will glad to help you.

Answer (score 4):

I use a string formats, as outlined on the [C# Examples](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/) page from www.csharp-examples.net:

```
String.Format("{0:t}", dt);  // "4:05 PM"                         ShortTime
String.Format("{0:d}", dt);  // "3/9/2008"                        ShortDate
```

Comment: My code is string sample="Wed May 25 23:43:31 UTC+0900 2011"; string.format is not working properly for above code.

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at the [msdn documentation around DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

You should pay particular attention to the parse function and the various ToString functions, being careful with which string formats you are passing in (or according to the current culture), to ensure you'll get the format your expecting.

Comment: No worries @Arun, I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which programming language you are using, but most have a function to break a string on whitespace.  You could break the string this way and then take the date elements out and use them.

Comment: Hi @astay13 you're right it's not that clear, but I believe Arun is using c# / asp.net as it says in the question tags.